# Kosher New World Animals

Tags: history, kashrut-kosher, animals

When Jews first set foot on new-to-them continents (AKA: North America, South America, and Australia), they would have found many animals that were previously unknown to them. Some of these new animals are kosher, and some are not. I'm trying to think of some new world animals that are kosher. So far I have [bison](http://www.kashrut.com/articles/buffalo/) and [turkey](http://www.kashrut.com/articles/turk_part5/) (although neither was done without controversy). Are there any more?

Comment: How 'bout the musk ox?

Comment: Consider too the muscovy duck https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/82302/759

Comment: Various deer- or elk-type species like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pronghorn but i don't know if that's different enough

Comment: Seems too broad.

Comment: The Grenada dove?

Comment: How about all New World bird species that aren't included in the Torah's list of forbidden types?

Comment: There would also be rather a lot of new fish meeting the Torah requirements for fish.

Answer (score 1):

I posted this elsewhere and Natan Slifkin and Elli Fischer came up with a few more. I'm just combining what I've gotten from several sources (including the comments above) into a single list of animals and birds. Note that all of these have some level of controversy around them and none are universally accepted, but all of these are accepted by someone and CYLOR for an actual psak on what's kosher.

- Moose
- Pronghorn
- Bison
- Bighorn sheep
- Dall sheep
- Musk Ox
- Turkey
- Muscovey Duck